# Align items to left while flex direction is row-reverse in Flex

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, direction

I want to display items in reverse order horizontally with left alignment

here is my working fiddle, but items are aligned to right.

```css
#main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#main div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```

can someone help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: `#main { justify-content: flex-end; }` is what you want.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to specify `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
#main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#main div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">A</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
  <div style="background-color:khaki;">C</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">D</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgrey;">E</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">F</div>
</div>
```